# Introducing the PPCG Sandbox Viewer™

Tags: discussion, sandbox, userscript

The sandbox post is really just a question which we use as a system to review posts (which is great and all), but wouldn't it be great if there could be like a *dedicated review queue* for Sandbox Post? Nobody made one so I took it upon myself to make one! After days and hours of work, I've finished up the viewer!

Well I've got the next best thing, a PPCG Sandbox Viewer!

---

### Screenshots

You're probably saying show me the damn viewer already so here some screenshots:

[image: PPCG Viewer]

**Note:** The buttons and links all change color depending on the SE site you open it from. This was opened on PPCG w/ the graduation userscript

Here's a GIF demonstrating it's use:

[image: GIF on Sandbox Viewer]

### Features

What does it do? Quite a bit actually:

- See your sandboxed Posts

  - See the score breakdown
  - See your posts latest activity
- See comments on your posts
- Review posts from the viewer
- Upvote / Downvote posts
- See / Expand posts comment threads
- Leave comments *from* the sandbox viewer
- The sandbox button lights up when a new sandbox posts is added

Have a feature request? Leave one! I really don't know what else to add

### Download

Convinced it's awesome? Download it!

#### [Install It!](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer/raw/master/viewer.v2.user.js)

#### [Installation link for Firefox (GreaseMonkey)](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer/raw/master/gm_viewer.v2.user.js)

<sub>* [Don't forget to star](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer) :3</sub>

This is a userscript, so make sure you have TamperMonkey (Now works on Firefox / GreaseMonkey!) installed and it should prompt you to install it.

### How do I use it?

This adds a little sandbox button to the header.

[image]

Click the `x` in the top-right corner of the viewer to exit it.

Comment: This is amazing, and I love it.

Comment: The `x` is in the top-left...

Comment: Nice comments in the latest activity bar, guys...

Comment: Omg, the "you suck" was what I thought reflexively in my head when I saw you click the comment box in the GIF... Then you actually typed it. Oh man, that was good.

Comment: I added it to Greasy Forge (gist wasn't working in firefox). Here's the link: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/35816-sandbox-viewer

Comment: Doesn't work with new SE header bar. Will you fix it or is this a dead project?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino yes will do

Comment: ...did it ever get updated?

Comment: @Corsaka It was updated with the new top bar but I haven't had time to maintain this for a long while now

Comment: @Downgoat Can you help me? In microsoft edge Windows 10 it says can't install extensions from this website.

Answer (score 18):

## Make it compatible with the new top bar

Since Stack Exchange has changed its top bar across all the sites in the network, one can no longer use the sandbox viewer. Here is how it looks like now:

[image]

As you can see the button is no longer there.

<sub>* <s>Also you cannot change the settings of the "PPCG Graduation" script)</s> ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))</sub>

Comment: I patched the script to work with the new sidebar. Where do I put it up?

Answer (score 11):

### Feature request: Sandbox Notification

Make the sandbox icon in the super collider show a notification when there's a new sandbox post since the last time you clicked it (much like the reputation icon next to it when you've only received a badge and it turns green... could be a different colour though... sand-coloured maybe).

Comment: [status-completed]: The button should become a [bright, sand color](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9eUzr.png) when a new post is sandboxed. I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: @Downgoat Doesn't seem to be working yet.

Comment: Apparently I don't know how websockets work :/ *now* this should work

Comment: @Downgoat Seems to be working now, but I think the change in colour could be a bit more noticeable.

Comment: @MartinEnder How can it be noticeable when you want the color of sand? Maybe the color of white sand?

Answer (score 9):

### Feature request: enter submits comment

Comments can't contain linefeeds, so like the comment field on SE itself, hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> should submit the comment.

Comment: Okay this has been added in 1.6

Answer (score 5):

## Feature Request: Port this to become PPCG Challenge Viewer

I was thinking, this works great with the sandbox, but why not make it into a challenge viewer? I've heard some chit chat about making an app for PPCG, but this would be a good experience for desktop users. Maybe an auto code golf sorter? Any input on this would be great.

Answer (score 4):

### Feature request: make the sidebar work from other SEs

When I open the viewer on another SE, I'm not seeing any challenges in the left sidebar. I'm assuming this is because you're using the user ID on the current SE (this would actually mean I might see someone else's list, if my ID on another SE matches up with theirs on PPCG). If at all possible, it would be neat if the script could determine my ID on PPCG and use that.

Comment: Not sure this is possible but I'll try.

Answer (score 3):

## Bug: Voting is cross-site request

When I upvoted, Tampermonkey saw it as a cross-site request and flagged it.

I'm not sure whether this a bug in the script or in SE, but I'll show it anyways:

[image]

Comment: It's because the userscript hasn't been updated to point to `https://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com` instead of `https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com` (the latter is a redirect tot he former).

Comment: Okay, I've fixed this as of 2.6

Answer (score 2):

## Troubleshooting/Error

Does not display any latest activity (I don't have sandboxed posts, at the moment). On latest Chrome/Tampermonkey (OSX, 64-bit).

[image: screenshot]

Also, just realized that upvoting one post locks in the upvote symbol like so:

[image]

While you can see that I have not (yet) upvoted that answer.

[image]

However, it did work for the one I first clicked on.

Comment: The latest activity is just comments on your posts but I guess that could be changed

Comment: Ah ok. I thought it was over all posts.

Comment: The vote thing is weird though I'll fix that

Comment: ok, it should be fixed in the latest commit. Let me know if it continues to not work for you

Comment: @Downgoat Unfortunately it doesn't process upvotes *or* downvotes for me now

Comment: :/ Firefox is very stubborn on letting me doing AJAX requests. I've fixed it for Chrome / Safari / etc. But Firefox support is still buggy.

Answer (score 2):

## Bug: WebSocket connection blocked when using https

```
Execution of script 'Sandbox Viewer' failed! Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

I notice you updated the http: URIs to use https: in the v2.4 commit but the websocket URI on line 351 is still using ws: instead of wss:

Comment: Okay, as of 2.5 (currently 2.6) this has been updated to wss

Answer (score 1):

## Bug: Post button doesn't work

I just installed this, Chrome/Tampermonkey, and the `Post` button, for  posting comments, doesn't work. It doesn't respond at all.

Comment: This should be fixed now. Error reporting is kinda crappy but hopefully it'll display an alert box if oyur comment is too short

Answer (score 1):

## *VERY* Important Feature Request: Add license

***Very Important: You only showed others the code, you did not share it, see [the GitHub blog](https://github.blog/2015-03-09-open-source-license-usage-on-github-com/) and [choosealicense.com](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/no-license). As I assume, the most popular license on GitHub is the most restrictive - no license, which applies the copyright law and makes code unusable. According to GitHub's TOS, you have granted others permission to see and fork the repository, so they can only do those actions, nothing else.***

"No license" has several cons. The MIT license has only a few cons, fewer than no license. I opened https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-SandboxViewer/pull/6 to solve this. When creating a repository, GitHub now removed the checkbox to add a license, and only the dropdown exists now. All my public repositories on GitHub.com have a license.

Answer (score 1):

## Nothing pops up

The sandbox icon does not pop up on the website header.

Comment: The script hasn't worked for years

Answer (score 0):

## Cutoff at top

[image]

Not sure if this is a my computer problem or not... but it's cutoff at the top and I can't see those buttons. My screen is 1920x1080.