# PPCG-specific Mobile App

Tags: discussion

#### [See a list of feature requests here (On hold)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12897/ppcg-specific-mobile-app-feature-requests)

Basically, I was wondering if anyone could develop a mobile app which would serve as a browser for PPCG. Maybe something along the lines of the pre-existing SE for mobile app. However, this would be specific to PPCG with special features as found in [the graduation design userscript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/graduation-design-ideas/7955#7955) (sort by byte count, automatic TIO links, [sandbox viewer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8474/introducing-the-ppcg-sandbox-viewer), etc.).

*Note:* Something to keep in mind is that, on current SE for mobile app, the sandbox is basically unusable due to huge number of answers.

As I have absolutely no Android/iOS programming experience, so if someone is willing to take the time to develop this, I'd love to use it.

### Bounty

As a reward for your hard effort, I will be willing to award a minimum of ***1300* rep bounty** to the best app (if multiple apps are posted). If an Android app and an iOS app is added, I will award two bounties. Since this is PPCG, let's make this a competition :D

---

[**Tuskiomi**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60951/tuskiomi) is willing to offer half their rep (at the time when the app is released) as a bounty to be awarded to the best app.

Comment: Also in favor. This would be great.

Comment: Yes, please have it by tomorrow.

Comment: @feersum I might be able to do Android, but expect 6-8 weeks delay

Comment: I think this would be great.

Comment: @Christopher I think I might up the bounty when I get enough rep

Comment: @BetaDecay tempting, I would not be good enough :(

Comment: I'm offering to do this, but a full specsheet (requirements, suggested functionality) would be necessary.

Comment: @VoteToClose Okay, that's fine. Could you maybe start what you're looking for off as an answer and convert it to CW so we can add the features

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Estimated completion date is November 1st.

Comment: @mbomb007 Don't give Geobits any ideas xD

Comment: I am totally open to making an iOS app for PPCG, but I have one question: does source code need to be golfed? :P

Comment: @EvilSheep Only if you want it to :)

Comment: This should totally become a code golf challenge :P

Comment: @numbermaniac Specifying this would be a nightmare though :P Maybe a pop-con

Comment: @feersum Wait... are... are you and my boss the same person?

Comment: Suggestion: Post each different feature proposal as an individual answer so people can vote on them. This would allow whoever's building it to prioritise the features we want the most.

Comment: @Shaggy [See here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12897/ppcg-specific-mobile-app-feature-requests)

Comment: @tuskiomi I've added it :)

Comment: @BetaDecay Thank you; an app for PPCG would be worth so much for us.

Comment: @BetaDecay I've thought about doing this before, since I've done some Android work and would like to have one. One day I decided to put it off until November, but still haven't decided which year.

Comment: @Geobits Haha hopefully *someone* will do it :D

Comment: Personally, I believe the app should be open-sourced, whether it be Android or iOS.

Comment: @Cowsquack That would be nice, but I don't think it's fair to enforce this

Comment: Hmmm this may be in my future.

Comment: @Christopher There's a lot of rep at stake ;)

Comment: @BetaDecay yeah I would become so rich

Comment: Maybe some mockups would help tempt some people to work on the app?

Comment: @totallyhuman I suppose, but I don't have the ability/skill to do that

Comment: I'll take a look after I finish my current project - shouldn't be too hard, just use the SE API. I guess React Native or NativeScript could be used to make it on both platforms easily

Comment: @OliverNi Thank you! I'm on a bit of a hiatus from PCG atm, but I'll probably return for this :D

Answer (score 9):

This answer is intended as community submission describing the target functionality. This will likely change over time, but it will allow devs to have a end goal with their program.

---

Obviously, this includes the standards (doing anything you would normally be able to do on the site), but also the below:

#### Better Sandbox

The Sandbox should load smoothly, be easy to use, and should NOT show deleted answers.

#### TIO Integration

Allowing users to test their code on the run would be infinitely helpful, since normally you'd have to wait until you had computer access. This would also make editing answers easier to do, since the answer can then be modified with the modified TIO-generated permalink.

#### Automatic Leaderboards

This is not only much more convenient than a Stack Snippet but also will be on every code-golf post, not just the ones with the Stack Snippet.

#### Improve Answer Sorting

There are two parts to this:

- Firstly, adding sort by byte count (for code golf)
- The default sort option should by changed for specific tags. For example, when the challenge is tagged with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the default sort should be by byte count

While possibly slightly more difficult, it might be worth adding a sort by score option for [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

#### Stack Snippet Support

This is probably impossible on a mobile device due to the requirement of JavaScript, HTML and CSS, but basically, it would be useful for when people post submissions in JS, to be able to run any stack snippets that they include in their answer.

#### Monospaced Font

It would be *very* useful for the app to use a monospaced font when writing answers and questions. This will allow code breakdowns and ASCII art to be designed in-situ.

Similarly, code blocks should use monospaced font.

Comment: The only problem I see with "Improve Answer Sorting" is that we don't have a formalized regex for bytecount.

Comment: Yes, I thought that. Maybe take the size of the first code block a la https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91989/count-the-bytes

Comment: @BetaDecay Actually that makes sense. :P

Comment: Maybe we can use another highlighting scheme instead of SO's default (we can make our own)?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Like [this does](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design)?

Comment: @BetaDecay that might not work if the programming language uses a custom code page/encoding. Example: `ç` is 2 bytes in utf-8, but only one in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Luke That's what I thought... It might be worth just counting characters instead as an estimation

Comment: A couple of suggestions that I don't quite have time to flesh out right now: 1) Include an option to find a random challenge you haven't answered yet, similar to (but more efficient than!) [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122400/58974).

Comment: 2) If possible, use [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/). If not, at least use [floating action buttons](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html) to add an answer when viewing a question and to post a challenge when viewing anything else. (Sidenote: an extensive collection of MD style icons can be found [here](https://materialdesignicons.com))

Comment: @Shaggy It might help to put these in the answer

Comment: @BetaDecay, I'll try to find a few minutes to write them up properly tomorrow, along with a couple of other ideas I had.

Comment: Anyone want to start on an iOS version? https://github.com/juniorRubyist/PPCG

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure we need chat integration (Because you know, the current mobile chat is quite buggy), but I do not know how. Maybe take a deep look into the source codes?

Comment: *The current mobile chat is quite buggy* - Are you sure? The mobile chat is on the same level as the main site chat IMO. Put it this way, it's much better than it used to be.