# PPCG-specific Mobile App: Feature Requests

Tags: discussion

#### [See main post here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12575/ppcg-specific-mobile-app)

> This [question] is intended as community submission describing the target functionality. This will likely change over time, but it will allow devs to have a end goal with their program. Obviously, this includes the standards (doing anything you would normally be able to do on the site), but also the below:

This question is a place to keep a list of feature requests. If you have a request for the PPCG mobile app, add it as an answer here.

If you like an answer, upvote it to increase its priority.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Meta is not the appropriate place to solicit feature requests.

Comment: @Mego Where else is this going to live though?

Comment: GitHub? Google Code? Sourceforge? Any one of the other repositories specifically designed for this purpose?

Comment: This is basically what [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12677/34718) is for.

Comment: @mego google code is shut down, IIRC

Comment: Sorry. I didn't envision your ideas.

Comment: We need to make it an instant app. Google now added that and it's *gooood*

Answer (score 8):

## Monospaced Font

It would be very useful for the app to use a monospaced font when writing answers and questions. This will allow code breakdowns and ASCII art to be designed in-situ.

Similarly, code blocks should use monospaced font.

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Answer (score 8):

## [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) Inegration

Include a feature to allow users to search for sequences or keywords in the OEIS.

Comment: Also add an option to automatically add the `[A123456]: https://oeis.org/A123456` at the bottom of the answer for each sequence you mention in the question/answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Better Sandbox

The Sandbox should load smoothly, be easy to use, and should NOT show deleted answers.

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Answer (score 7):

## TIO Integration

Allowing users to test their code on the run would be infinitely helpful, since normally you'd have to wait until you had computer access. This would also make editing answers easier to do, since the answer can then be modified with the modified TIO-generated permalink.

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Answer (score 7):

## Find a Random Challenge

Include an option to find a random challenge you haven't answered yet, similar to (but more efficient than!) [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122400/58974). The tags used could either be:

- Randomly pulled from your favourite tags.
- Defined by a user setting.
- Selectable every time the feature is used.

The limitation on the number of answers may need to be removed, or be defined by a user setting.

Answer (score 7):

## Deleted Answers Toggle

Add a setting to allow users to toggle whether or not deleted solutions are displayed while using the app.

Answer (score 6):

## Push Notifications

Include push notifications for everything that you normally get notifications for on the site, such as comments, chat pings, new answers to your challenges, edits to your posts, etc., etc.

Add a notification, if it's possible, for new & updated Sandbox posts.

All of the above should be configurable through user settings.

Answer (score 5):

## Edit Histories & Rollbacks

Include the ability to view edit histories and to roll posts back to previous versions.

Answer (score 4):

## Automatic Leaderboards

This is not only much more convenient than a Stack Snippet but also will be on every code-golf post, not just the ones with the Stack Snippet.

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Answer (score 4):

## Stack Snippet Support

This is probably impossible on a mobile device due to the requirement of JavaScript, HTML and CSS, but basically, it would be useful for when people post submissions in JS, to be able to run any stack snippets that they include in their answer.

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Answer (score 4):

## Template(s) for answers

There should be an option to automatically convert some code in an answer to the format:

```
<lang>, <n> bytes
    <code here>
[Try it online!](<link>) (If selected lang exists on TIO)
```

Comment: if the question has the [tips] tag, then disable this

Comment: @dzaima It needn't be an automatic thing. You could just not push the button.

Answer (score 4):

## Use Custom Codepages for Byte Counts

Like the graduation userscript, when finding the byte count of the submission, the app should use specific languages' [custom codepages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each).

This would be helpful for Jelly, APL, etc.

Answer (score 3):

## Improve Answer Sorting

There are two parts to this:

- Firstly, adding sort by byte count (for code golf)
- The default sort option should by changed for specific tags. For example, when the challenge is tagged with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), the default sort should be by byte count

While possibly slightly more difficult, it might be worth adding a sort by score option for [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Not necessarily, I copied these over from [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12677/30525). Not all of these were suggested by me

Answer (score 3):

## [Floating Action Buttons](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html)

- When viewing a challenge, the FAB would allow you to post a solution.
- When viewing any other page, the FAB would allow you to post a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## Language Filter / Search Answers

When viewing a challenge add the ability to filter answers by language or add a field to "find in page".

Answer (score 1):

## Universal Windows Platform/Windows Phone Support

Pretty please?
There are *dozens* of us!

Answer (score -5):

## Use [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/)

If possible, use Google's Material Design ,for the Android app, at least.

An extensive collection of MD style icons for use with such a design can be found [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/) and includes most of the icons from Google's own icon library.
<sub>Disclosure: I am a contributor to their GitHub project</sub>

Comment: Why the hate for Material Design?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that this is an advertisement for Material rather than a useful feature for the app

Answer (score -6):

## Sandbox Prompt

This may prove to more of an annoyance than anything else but, when posting to main, include some sort of prompt to post to the Sandbox first.

Comment: I think most users of the app would probably already have a good idea of how PPCG works, including the sandbox.

Comment: A fair point, @ETHproductions. I was thinking of the general membership when I wrote this up but, you're right, anyone serious enough about this site to download a dedicated app is already aware of the Sandbox and, if they're not using it, in-app prompts aren't going to change that.