# How long is it before we get our own design?

Tags: discussion, site-design

We have exited beta now, as far as I can tell.

However, the site looks identical to most beta sites.

When will we make our own design?

Comment: Relevant: [How long until graduated sites get a new site design and increased privileges threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290359)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know SE is looking into implementing new features, which PPCG would also benefit from. It seems that they want to wait with producing a design until those features are worked out, because the design could be affected by them, see e.g. [here](http://disq.us/p/1fnnnoa).

Comment: Has anyone seen the new Stack Overflow design? I'm wondering if the other sites will get that.

Answer (score -3):

I'd actually prefer it if the site doesn't get a design at all; the vast majority of Stack Exchange designs make the site both ugly, and hard to read at a glance, whereas the beta theme is clear and simple.

Even if the site does get a design, there are changes which are rather more pressing; [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8350/62131) lists a number of potential changes from Stack Exchange's end that could help the site function better, and many of those have higher priority than a design would. Things like a custom Tour page would be highly useful, because the site interface currently gives outright misleading information on how the site works.

Comment: This is a pretty rude response. I personally think that the individualized designs look nice; others may agree.