# Make it easier to post answers on Sandbox from Mobile App?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, sandbox

Maybe I'm missing something, but is there an easy-ish way to initiate the process of writing an answer in the Sandbox from the mobile app? I noticed the phrase "bottom of the page" in the sandbox question was a link and I clicked on it, only to be brought recursively to the question, so I don't think that's much help for me.

I'm going to post this as a low priority feature request unless someone gives me a better idea or a solution that I may have overlooked.

Comment: I'm not sure that this can be solved without SE's help. This might be a better request for [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8350/45941).

Comment: I have definitely noticed the same behavior, since I regularly use SE in general from mobile. Unfortunately, I think the sandbox is pretty much unusable from the app. Thankfully, if you use your phone's browser, it will force it to load in pages, making it much more manageable.

Comment: The way I do it is check my current proposals so it hides all but one, then click the add an answer button

Comment: Oh, I'll try that next time I'm on my phone...

Comment: As per [this MM answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353133/why-did-the-stack-exchange-android-app-disappear-from-the-play-store/363043#363043), SE isn't going to be making mobile apps anymore, so I've marked this as [meta-tag:status-declined]. Thanks.