# can "actual problems" be removed from /help/dont-ask?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I noticed that https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." However, at least 70% of code golfing is done just for fun, and isn't based on actual problems faced (If they had real business use cases, they probably should be in StackOverflow instead.)

Can that sentence be reworded or removed?

Comment: AFAIK we haven't yet been able to customize our help page.

Comment: ah, that explains a lot (and probably answers my question... with a no)

Comment: Here you go: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8351/65836, I'll mark it as a dupe

Comment: I've marked this as [meta-tag:status-declined] since I can't actually edit this page. This might be worth asking as a specific feature request for "let us edit these pages" but I think we've had stuff like that to no avail in the past, unfortunately :(