# Should we change the question on the Tour page?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, new-users, help-center

The [Tour](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour) is a page shown to new users, intended as a quick introduction to the site. As part of this, there's an example question shown to the user:

[image: Question ("Triangle Area Side Side Side") with some information]

The current question, [Triangle Area Side Side Side](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11020/triangle-area-side-side-side), is both closed and inconsistent with the expectations for a new challenge. It has a brief description, badly formatted test cases (and only two of them), and no details on things like allowed input/output methods.

**Should we choose a new question?** Answers here should either be "no", or a proposal for a specific question to replace it with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes, to [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85/66833)

- The challenge is short, so will fit into the cropped view from the tour page, but is still a well specified and clear challenge
- It's been consistently active for over 10 years. Looking at the [timeline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/85/timeline), there's been an answer posted at least once a month, every month since posting. This means we'll be demonstrating to new users that old posts are by no means forgotten, and that answering old posts is encouraged
- The top answers by votes, and therefore the two shown in the Tour, are Perl and brainfuck, which I think are great examples of what we do here. The Perl program shows to new users the extent to which we can twist "practical" languages to be incredibly short; the brainfuck program demonstrates a famous esoteric language to those who are less likely to be familiar with them
- It has an accepted answer. Even if we [discourage accepting answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8363/66833), it's still a core functionality of the SE platform, and should be demonstrated in the Tour page
- The "test cases" are prominently featured, close to the top of the question, so won't be cropped out in the Tour
- It's a very famous beginner programming task, up there with Fizz Buzz and Hello, World!, so a lot of people are likely to see it and think "Oh, I know how to do that", encouraging them to participate

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, to [The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210071/78410)

When I was writing this challenge, I tried to make many of the implicit rules explicit, such as default I/O methods, standard loopholes, built-ins, time/memory limits, and "theoretically being correct is valid". I think this list serves as a brief guideline for new plain code golf challenges. If others think it matters, I can add links to the relevant meta posts for each of them.

Comment: Maybe we should change the title - "vanilla" comes close to being a meta tag (although it's not in the tags) and requires a bit of knowledge of the history of the site

Comment: Also, does the tour page require the question to have an accepted answer? If not, don't add one, since that's not recommended here

Comment: @pxeger I agree that "vanilla" is not the best word that fits into the tour page. Any suggestions welcome. Also agreed to the accepted answer thing.

Comment: Maybe "simplified"? or just "simple"?